# PayPal return URL with transaction or payment ID?

Tags: paypal

I'm using the following script to display a PP button on my website which works fine. You'll see that I have a return URL which also pulls in data (eg orderid) from my page:

```
    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({

        // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: '2.00' // Can reference variables or functions. Example: `value: document.getElementById('...').value`
              }
            }]
          });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                window.location.href = 'https://mywebsite.co.uk/signup-payment-confirmation.asp?fee=<%=fee%>&ct=<%=orderid%>';;
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
```

This works fine as when a transaction is made the user is simply redirected to the return URL and I record the data in my database. However, what I really need is for my return URL to also show the transaction ID from the PayPal transaction. I can then tally records in my database to those in the PayPal admin area.

Answer (score 0):

actions.order.create / .capture are for simple use cases. If you intend to do anything with a database, do not use these client side functions. Any number of problems could prevent your system from recording a transaction after the fact.

Instead, use the actual v2/checkout/orders API and make two routes (url paths) on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You could use one of the (recently deprecated) Checkout-*-SDKs for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTPS implementation of first getting an access token and then doing the call. Both of these routes should return/output **only** JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as reserving product or sending an email) immediately *before* forwarding return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)